# NSPredicate not giving result as expected

Tags: objective-c, filter, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have `NSMutableArray` as below.

```
(
        {
        "Carton_Apartment" = "";
        "Carton_AreaCode" = 111;
        "Carton_AreaGroupCode" = 1;
        "Carton_AreaGroupName" = Group1;
        "Carton_AreaName" = Bayan;
        "Carton_Avenue" = "";
        "Carton_Block" = 1;
        "Carton_CartonNumber" = 1;
        "Carton_CustomerCode" = 6880;
        "Carton_CustomerName" = "Name 1";
        "Carton_DeliveryNotes" = YES;
        "Carton_DeliveryShiftCode" = 1;
        "Carton_DietType" = "LBS-750";
        "Carton_Floor" = "";
        "Carton_HomeNo" = 45;
        "Carton_HomePhone" = 111111;
        "Carton_IsDelivered" = false;
        "Carton_Latitude" = "";
        "Carton_Longitude" = "";
        "Carton_Mobile" = 1111111;
        "Carton_OfficePhone" = "";
        "Carton_StreetName" = 2;
        "Carton_SubscriptionDate" = "2014-04-29T00:00:00";
        "Carton_Title" = "Mrs.";
    },
        {
        "Carton_Apartment" = "";
        "Carton_AreaCode" = 111;
        "Carton_AreaGroupCode" = 1;
        "Carton_AreaGroupName" = Group1;
        "Carton_AreaName" = Bayan;
        "Carton_Avenue" = "";
        "Carton_Block" = 1;
        "Carton_CartonNumber" = 2;
        "Carton_CustomerCode" = 8314;
        "Carton_CustomerName" = "Name 2";
        "Carton_DeliveryNotes" = YES;
        "Carton_DeliveryShiftCode" = 1;
        "Carton_DietType" = ND1350;
        "Carton_Floor" = "";
        "Carton_HomeNo" = 45;
        "Carton_HomePhone" = 222222;
        "Carton_IsDelivered" = false;
        "Carton_Latitude" = "";
        "Carton_Longitude" = "";
        "Carton_Mobile" = 111111;
        "Carton_OfficePhone" = "";
        "Carton_StreetName" = 2;
        "Carton_SubscriptionDate" = "2014-04-29T00:00:00";
        "Carton_Title" = "Mr.";
    }
)
```

Actually this array is of length of size more then 500.

Now I am trying to extract array based on `Carton_CartonNumber`. So I tried using `NSPredicate` as below.

```
NSPredicate *predFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Carton_CartonNumber = %d", 2];
                                                            ^ this is coming from another array as intValue

NSArray *predArray = [shiftsCartoonsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predFilter];
```

When I try to print the data for `predArray` I get nothing.

Any idea why this is happening?

---

### Answer

I noticed that number was string and not integer and because of that I had to enclose in single quotes..

Below did the trick...

```
NSPredicate *predFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Carton_CartonNumber = '%d'", 2];
                                                       ^  ^ 

NSArray *predArray = [shiftsCartoonsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predFilter];
```

Comment: In your code, `predArray` uses `mmfilter`, not `predFilter`. Could this be the problem. I just ran your code and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that `Carton_CartonNumber` was string and not integer and because of that I had to enclose in single quotes..

Below did the trick...

```
NSPredicate *predFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Carton_CartonNumber = '%d'", 2];
                                                       ^  ^ 

NSArray *predArray = [shiftsCartoonsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predFilter];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *searchString = @"2"; 

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"Carton_CartonNumber == %@",
                                    searchString];
NSArray *filteredArray = [shiftsCartoonsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Comment: What is the difference between `@"Carton_CartonNumber == %d", [searchString intValue]` and `@"Carton_CartonNumber == %@", searchString]`. **Afterall they are NSString ONLY**

Comment: The first one was if you are storing it as an integer then convert it into int value

else its a string value.

Comment: @FahimParkar, the difference in this answer is that he's using `[predicateWithFormat:@"..."]` and not `[predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat@"..."]]`. That means that @Chetan's version actually lets `NSPredicate` handle the formatting, instead of just feeding it a simple string, which is what your answer does.

Comment: Interesting. I tried it and it worked perfectly. If I use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Carton_CartonNumber == %@", @"2"]` I get the correct answer, but if I use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Carton_CartonNumber == %d", 2]` it fails.

Comment: @GuyKogus : See the edited answer.. Thats working for me. The %d part was wrong.. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

The following code works just fine:

```
NSArray *array = @[
                   @{
                       @"Carton_Apartment" : @"",
                       @"Carton_AreaCode" : @111,
                       @"Carton_AreaGroupCode" : @1,
                       @"Carton_AreaGroupName" : @"Group1",
                       @"Carton_AreaName" : @"Bayan",
                       @"Carton_Avenue" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Block" : @1,
                       @"Carton_CartonNumber" : @1,
                       @"Carton_CustomerCode" : @6880,
                       @"Carton_CustomerName" : @"Name 1",
                       @"Carton_DeliveryNotes" : @YES,
                       @"Carton_DeliveryShiftCode" : @1,
                       @"Carton_DietType" : @"LBS-750",
                       @"Carton_Floor" : @"",
                       @"Carton_HomeNo" : @45,
                       @"Carton_HomePhone" : @111111,
                       @"Carton_IsDelivered" : @NO,
                       @"Carton_Latitude" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Longitude" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Mobile" : @1111111,
                       @"Carton_OfficePhone" : @"",
                       @"Carton_StreetName" : @2,
                       @"Carton_SubscriptionDate" : @"2014-04-29T00:00:00",
                       @"Carton_Title" : @"Mrs."
                       },
                   @{
                       @"Carton_Apartment" : @"",
                       @"Carton_AreaCode" : @111,
                       @"Carton_AreaGroupCode" : @1,
                       @"Carton_AreaGroupName" : @"Group1",
                       @"Carton_AreaName" : @"Bayan",
                       @"Carton_Avenue" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Block" : @1,
                       @"Carton_CartonNumber" : @2,
                       @"Carton_CustomerCode" : @8314,
                       @"Carton_CustomerName" : @"Name 2",
                       @"Carton_DeliveryNotes" : @YES,
                       @"Carton_DeliveryShiftCode" : @1,
                       @"Carton_DietType" : @"ND1350",
                       @"Carton_Floor" : @"",
                       @"Carton_HomeNo" : @45,
                       @"Carton_HomePhone" : @222222,
                       @"Carton_IsDelivered" : @NO,
                       @"Carton_Latitude" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Longitude" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Mobile" : @111111,
                       @"Carton_OfficePhone" : @"",
                       @"Carton_StreetName" : @2,
                       @"Carton_SubscriptionDate" : @"2014-04-29T00:00:00",
                       @"Carton_Title" : @"Mr."
                       }
                   ];
NSPredicate *predFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Carton_CartonNumber = %d", 2]];
NSLog(@"%@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predFilter]);
```

Your problem is not with the predicate you're using.

**Update**

I was wrong and it `is` the predicate that's the problem, as you've stated in the comments that `Carton_CartonNumber` is a string. I updated the above code to be:

```
NSArray *array = @[
                   @{
                       @"Carton_Apartment" : @"",
                       @"Carton_AreaCode" : @111,
                       @"Carton_AreaGroupCode" : @1,
                       @"Carton_AreaGroupName" : @"Group1",
                       @"Carton_AreaName" : @"Bayan",
                       @"Carton_Avenue" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Block" : @1,
                       @"Carton_CartonNumber" : @"1",
                       @"Carton_CustomerCode" : @6880,
                       @"Carton_CustomerName" : @"Name 1",
                       @"Carton_DeliveryNotes" : @YES,
                       @"Carton_DeliveryShiftCode" : @1,
                       @"Carton_DietType" : @"LBS-750",
                       @"Carton_Floor" : @"",
                       @"Carton_HomeNo" : @45,
                       @"Carton_HomePhone" : @111111,
                       @"Carton_IsDelivered" : @NO,
                       @"Carton_Latitude" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Longitude" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Mobile" : @1111111,
                       @"Carton_OfficePhone" : @"",
                       @"Carton_StreetName" : @2,
                       @"Carton_SubscriptionDate" : @"2014-04-29T00:00:00",
                       @"Carton_Title" : @"Mrs."
                       },
                   @{
                       @"Carton_Apartment" : @"",
                       @"Carton_AreaCode" : @111,
                       @"Carton_AreaGroupCode" : @1,
                       @"Carton_AreaGroupName" : @"Group1",
                       @"Carton_AreaName" : @"Bayan",
                       @"Carton_Avenue" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Block" : @1,
                       @"Carton_CartonNumber" : @"2",
                       @"Carton_CustomerCode" : @8314,
                       @"Carton_CustomerName" : @"Name 2",
                       @"Carton_DeliveryNotes" : @YES,
                       @"Carton_DeliveryShiftCode" : @1,
                       @"Carton_DietType" : @"ND1350",
                       @"Carton_Floor" : @"",
                       @"Carton_HomeNo" : @45,
                       @"Carton_HomePhone" : @222222,
                       @"Carton_IsDelivered" : @NO,
                       @"Carton_Latitude" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Longitude" : @"",
                       @"Carton_Mobile" : @111111,
                       @"Carton_OfficePhone" : @"",
                       @"Carton_StreetName" : @2,
                       @"Carton_SubscriptionDate" : @"2014-04-29T00:00:00",
                       @"Carton_Title" : @"Mr."
                       }
                   ];
NSPredicate *predFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Carton_CartonNumber = \"%d\"", 2]];
NSLog(@"%@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predFilter]);
```

You'll find the proper predicate that you're looking for in the updated code above.

Comment: **Chetan**'s answer above is cleaner. I recommend using that one instead.